# Are the docs for HashAlgorithm's "Create" method deficient?

Tags: c#, .net, security, hash, cryptography

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a table with the values that are valid for the method. But `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA1Cng` succeed even though they're not on the list.

i.e.

```
HashAlgorithm.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng");
```

Are the docs incomplete, or am I misunderstanding them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the MSDN documentation is not up to date?

if you want the full list, it seem you can find it [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptoconfig.cs.html) between lines 114 and 460.

You can also see it if you compile a sample application and look at the method call with ilspy, you can find the list from there too.

there is way more possible choice than what is listed on the MSDN link that you provided

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you are misunderstanding anything. The documentation appears to be not only incomplete, but incorrect.

Not only are there other values that return instances of hash algorithms, but the lookup table it uses can cause it to throw an exceptions instead of returning `null`.

For instance, each of the following will throw an `InvalidCastException`, but the documentation specifically states that it should return `null`.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create("1.2.840.113549.1.9.3");
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create("Triple DES");
System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create("X509Chain");
```

Comment: Welcome jmc, great way to start :)

Comment: Thanks. It'll be nice to finally be able to comment.